# Magento2.2 uiComponent tab in edit page

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, tabs

Trying to figure out how to add a Tab menu on my custom module edit page.

What I want to accomplish, is like in Magento 1, go to edit page of my custom module en see on the left multiple sections where are different forms and/or grids loaded.

I can see how magento2 now has it with Block/Edit/Tabs but this is deprecated so I want to try it with uiComponents.

What I got so far is a standard module where I can view the grid and add/edit/delete my stuff.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you can use multiple fieldsets in your uiComponent just like Magento used in new category form page.

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/adminhtml/ui_component/category_form.xml
```

Note: This doesn't show tabs like Magento-1 but has different sections on one page which work exactly like tabs.

Comment: Thank you, that helped for me to understand how magento 2 sees tabs. Was trying to get the same result as in Magento 1 ( some modules in magento 2 got it also that way ) 
Do you also maybe know if i can add a custom grid in the tab where i can on the fly add new records?
My goal is that i have a printing table with printing costs for 1 color 1 till 9 1 color 10 till 20 etc.

Comment: No, you can't add records on the fly in tab's grid. You can have a grid in the form's tab though. but that would be information grid or select/un-select record from the grid. just like the category form has the products grid in one of its tabs.

Comment: Thanks again!
Can i load a uiComponent grid inside the fieldset tab? Or do i have to create a custom grid for this..?

Comment: Probably, you have to create a custom grid for that.